# Thread safety in Objective-C categories

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a category on NSString:

```
- (CGSize) agb_sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font width:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode {
    if (!font) return CGSizeZero;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

    // this line is not threadsafe
    NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self attributes:attributes];

    CGRect bounds = [as boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 10000) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin) context:nil];
    return CGSizeMake(width, bounds.size.height);
}
```

I've observed intermittent `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes when running this code on multiple threads (sometimes in `initWithString: attributes:`, sometimes in `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`).

I believe my code is not thread-safe because `self` might deallocate on one thread while `initWithString: attributes:` is executing on the other.

1. Is my conclusion about this method's thread safety correct?
2. Would this code make it thread-safe?

   ```
   NSString *strongSelf = self;
   NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strongSelf attributes:attributes];
   ```

   (By maintaining a reference to `self`, I attempt to ensure the object in memory is not deallocated while I'm using it.)
3. Is there any way to declare this method as *not thread-safe*?  I'd love to generate a warning, for example, if a string declared as a `nonatomic` property is passed into this method.

Note: In case it's not obvious, I'm using ARC.

Comment: is ARC enabled? with ARC, object won't be deallocated while executing its method

Comment: @BryanChen Yes, ARC is enabled.  Are you sure this is true of category methods?

Comment: There's absolutely no difference between methods from a category and methods declared elsewhere with regard to threading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks like ARC enabled so I assume it is enabled.

> self might deallocate on one thread while initWithString: attributes: is executing on the other.

this is not possible with ARC, because in order to execute `agb_sizeWithFont...` method, you must doing something like this

```
NSString *str = /*...*/; // this will create a strong reference to str
[str agb_sizeWithFont:/*...*/]; // even str is released in other thread at this point, it won't be deallocated
```

---

```
NSString *strongSelf = self;
```

this code just create an extra strong reference to `self`, but since `self` must be retained somewhere already, it won't change anything

I don't think you can declare anything to be "not thread-safe" (actually everything are not thread-safe by default) and I don't understand how you want to use such warning.

---

methods in category have no difference compare to method in `@implementation` regards to thread-safety.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Do you know of any documentation that category methods are no different in regards to thread safety?  Can you think of any other possible causes of the crashes I described?

Comment: I don't know any doc mentions it though... Can you show how your method is used? it the string shared in multiple threads? is it `NSMutableString`? also did you enable NSZombie?

Comment: It is NSString, not NSMutableString.  It is used to calculate size on a background thread; this size added to some other sizes, cached, and later used in `[UITableViewDelegate -heightForRowAtIndexPath:]`.

Comment: Documenting that would be like documenting the fact that a code file's name has no effect on the arithmetic inside, @AaronBrager; there's just no relationship. Category methods' functionalities are indistinguishable from other methods. I don't even think the runtime preserves the information that they come from a category.

Answer (score 6):

Any `NSMutableString` is-a `NSString`, too. Any method you add to `NSString` in a category can therefore be invoked on an `NSMutableString`, too. It is not safe to operate on a mutable string on one thread if it might be being mutated at the same time on another thread. It is safe to *read* a mutable string while it is being read on another thread.

Since your invocation of `-[NSAttributedString initWithString:attributes:]` is reading from the string `self`, that's not safe to do if `self` is a mutable string and might be mutated on another thread at the same time.

You might be tempted to review all calls of `-agb_sizeWithFont:width:lineBreakMode:` to see if the type of the receiver is `NSMutableString*`. However, that's not sufficient. An instance of `NSMutableString` may be pointed to by a variable of type `NSString*` (or other things like `NSObject*` or `id`), too.

You won't be able to make `-agb_sizeWithFont:width:lineBreakMode:` thread-safe, as such. Thread-safety doesn't decompose. It will have to be designed into the code which manages whatever strings it might be invoked on. That is, all of the code which touches a given string object and might invoke your method and, in other places, might mutate it, must be in charge of making sure that only one of those things is happening at a time.